# Java object equals method not work

Tags: java

I have trouble with my code, the equals method is not working, I have try both `==` and `.equals()` but it's not working.

This is the code for main method:

```
x= new Card('♠',"number","3",5,Color.BLACK);
y= new Card('♠',"number","3",5,Color.BLACK);
if(x.equals(y)) System.out.println("True"); else System.out.println("False");
```

The program is printing "False" in the screen.

this is my Card class :

```
package core;

import java.awt.Color;

public class Card {
    private char symbol;
    private String type,value;
    private int score;
    private Color warna;
    public Card(char symbol, String type, String value,int score,Color warna)
    {
        this.setSymbol(symbol);
        this.setValue(value);
        this.setType(type);
        this.setScore(score);
        this.warna = warna;
    }
    public char getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    public void setSymbol(char symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public Color getWarna() {
        return warna;
    }
    public void setWarna(Color warna) {
        this.warna = warna;
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: If you have a trouble with your equals method, you should post it here.

Comment: Did you override the `equals` method in `Card`?

Comment: == just compares the references and sees if they point to the same object. 'Equals()' is supposed to compare the objects, but if you make a new type, you have to specify how the comparison works.

Comment: You did'nt override the method `equals` in your class. Google _"how to override equals()"_.

Comment: i didn't override the equals method.

Comment: @Mukhlas1940 If you want to use equals() to compare your objects, you need to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case:

**Right:** `if ( x.equals(y) )`

**Wrong:** `if ( x == y )`

If the `equals` API is not working, then you've overridden it in your `Card` class, and you've implemented it wrong.

If you haven't overridden it, well then do it:

```
public class Card 
{
    ...
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
            
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Card)) 
            return false;
        
        Card otherCard = (Card) obj;
        
        if (otherCard.score != this.score)       return false;
        if (otherCard.symbol != this.symbol)     return false;
        if (!otherCard.warna.equals(this.warna)) return false;
        if (!otherCard.type.equals(this.type))   return false;
        if (!otherCard.value.equals(this.value)) return false;
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not using the `equals()` method, but is testing reference equality of the 2 instances:

```
if(x==y)
```

You need to call the `equals()` method if you want to use it.

UPDATE:

The `equals()` test is not working because you have not overridden the default `Object.equals()` method, which only tests reference equality.

Answer (score 1):

By default `equals()` method is inherited from super class. If your class doesn't extend any class then it was inherited from Object class so it looks like

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

so for now it only checks if you are comparing you object with itself. In this case you need to override this method to check if you are comparing your object with object of same class (or derived one), compare value of fields of compared object. Here is example of such implementation.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof YourClass))
        return false;

    YourClass other = (YourClass) obj;
    //if field1 is primitive type
    if (field1 != other.field1)
        return false;
    //if field2 is object type
    if (field2 == null || other.field2 != null)
        return false;
    else if (!field2.equals(other.field2))
        return false;
    //rest of fields
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because "==" only checks if x and y refer to the same object. To check if they are equal, you want to override the Object.equals(Object) method from the `Object` class in your `Card` class, and then do `if(x.equals(y))` instead of `if(x == y)`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

This is a little bit of a complicated process, but basically you'll want...

```
@Override
boolean equals(Object obj)
{
   if(this == obj) //Check if they're the same object
   return true;
   else if(!(obj instanceof Card)) //Check if it is not a Card
   return false
   else //Else...
   Card other = (Card) obj;
   /*Check if the variables are equal*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if(x==y) evaluates to true only when both the variables are referring to the same object.

and for equals, did you override the equals method? it is better to override the equals method when you want to compare two objects.